# How would I go about getting all the assets of an address?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand

So I'm trying to find out how can i get list of all the assets that are owned by a single address on Algorand.

How do I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty simple.

you can get list of all existing address from Algorand indexer from [following API](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/rest-apis/algod/v2/#account).

[image: List Of Address]

Once you've list of address you can pick one you want to use to get list of all the assets on that address.

It can be done simply by querying that address on API for assets.

```
localhost:8980/v2/accounts/{address}/assets
```

more info about this can be [found here](https://developer.algorand.org/docs/rest-apis/algod/v2/#get-v2assetsasset-id)

[image: Asset List]

After this you can get more details about each asset from it's asset id.

And That's It! - **if you found it helpful make sure to upvote this answer :)**.

Comment: Is there any way to fetch all NFTs from an account without using any APIs ( like opensea, algorant, moralis )?